# Add text to several files in directories with conditions (Java)

Tags: java, directory, filewriter, file-read

I have one directory containing a bunch of subdirectories each one containing several text files. Each one of the subdirectories contains a text file which shares the same name as the subdirectory which contains it; I want to add the content of this file to all the other text files, except for the one that shares the name with the subdirectory, and I want to make it in java.

For example given the dir "a", containing subdirs "b","c","d", containing respectively files "b", "e", "f", and "c", "g", "h", and "d", "i", "j", I want to have the dir "a" containing subdirs "b","c","d" containing respectively files "b", "b+e", "b+f", and "c", "c+g", "c+h", and "d", "d+i", "d+j", and possibly deleting the added files, that is the files "a", "b", "c".

```
final File folder = new File("/path-of-directory/");

public static void listFilesForFolder(final File folder) {
    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
            listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
        } else if (fileEntry.getName().substring(0, fileEntry.getName().lastIndexOf(".")).toLowerCase().equals(folder.getName().toLowerCase()))
        
               // found the file which content has to be added to other files in the same directory. How to?
        }
}
```

Comment: First you will have to try writing some code and then share it with us if you encounter specific issues.

Comment: final File folder = new File("/path-of-directory/");
    
    public static void listFilesForFolder(final File folder) {
        for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
            } else if (fileEntry.getName().substring(0, fileEntry.getName().lastIndexOf(".")).toLowerCase().equals(folder.getName().toLowerCase()))
   
                   // found the file wich content has to be addes to other files in the same directory. How to?
            }
    }

Comment: Please edit your answer to update it with any additional information (like code above) and do not forget to format it.

Comment: pardon, thanks. Newbie issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked just fine for me, make sure to read the comments for details:

```
public class FileCopy {

    public static void recursivelyCopyContent(final File folder) {
        for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                recursivelyCopyContent(fileEntry);
            } else if (fileEntry.getName().substring(0, fileEntry.getName().lastIndexOf(".")).toLowerCase().equals(folder.getName().toLowerCase())) {
                // just pass the folder and the file to the method that will do the actual content copy 
                copyContent(folder, fileEntry);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void copyContent(final File folder, final File fileName) {
        try {
             // get the byte[] content of the source file
            byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(fileName.toPath());
            for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
                // only select files with a different absolute path than the source one
                if(fileEntry.isFile() && !fileEntry.getAbsolutePath().equals(fileName.getAbsolutePath())) {
                    // append contents from source to destination file 
                    Files.write(fileEntry.toPath(), fileContent, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
                }
            }
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final File folder = new File("/path-of-directory/");
        FileCopy.recursivelyCopyContent(folder);
    }
}
```

Just pay attention to files without extension: your condition

```
fileEntry.getName().substring(0, fileEntry.getName().lastIndexOf(".")).toLowerCase().equals(folder.getName().toLowerCase())
```

will throw `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` since no `.` character exists in their name.

In this case, I suggest the following approach:

```
// both cases covered: files have or do not have an extension
if (
    (!fileEntry.getName().contains(".") && fileEntry.getName().toLowerCase().equals(folder.getName().toLowerCase())) ||
    (fileEntry.getName().contains(".") && fileEntry.getName().substring(0, fileEntry.getName().lastIndexOf(".")).toLowerCase().equals(folder.getName().toLowerCase())) 
)
```

Comment: Your solution works just fine, except for the call to "listFilesForFolder" wich was the old method name. Replacing it with recursivelyCopyContent and changing the signature works fine for me too.

Comment: I just tried to add a more suggestive name to it. You are free to change it back if you like, this was not an issue.

Comment: I meant the call listFilesForFolder(fileEntry) on the fifth row of your solution, wich should be  recursivelyCopyContent(fileEntry) because the name of the recursive method is no more "listFilesForFolder".